# Agregar encabezados de seguridad a mi stio web HTML

Tags: html, seguridad, headers, cabeceras-http, security

Hola he estado intentando introducir los encabezados de seguridad sugeridos en el archivo htaccess del public_html que es donde esta mi sitio web

```
<IfModule mod_headers>
Header set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests"
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
Header set X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
Header set Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
Header set Permissions-Policy "geolocation=self"
</IfModule>
```

El problema es que al escanear el sitio con las herramientas que me confirman si se ha integrado correctamente no marca que se haya realizado de manera adecuada.

¿Hay alguna otra forma de realizarlo para que se refleje? Mi sitio se encuentra en un servidor Apache.

Comment: ¿Con que herramienta confirmas?

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 Header add Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests"
 Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
 Header add X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block"
 Header add X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
 Header add Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
 Header add Permissions-Policy "geolocation=self"
</IfModule>
```

El modulo Headers tiene que estar activo en el servidor